# How to configure Tomcat to use local IP address rather than localhost:8080 without editing files outside of the source code file

Tags: tomcat, server, ip-address, tomcat9

### Goal

My goal is  to configure Tomcat to use Single IP Address (My local IP Address) to host

www.'myip'-1.com

www.'myip'-2.com

The -1 and -2 should be the .html file name.

All without editing files outside of the source code file. (Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\source code file)

### What I have seen

From what I have gathered online, to do this will require editing file/s outside of the source code file, which is what I am trying to avoid. If this is not possible, please do tell me.

### Second goal

I would also like to have my document roots be as below, also without editing files outside of the source code file, but one problem at a time, so this is secondary. Again, if not possible, please do tell me.

C:/vhosts/myip-1

C:/vhosts/myip-2

Comment: You're using an application server (or servlet container) so that you don't need to do everything in source... Your limitations (where not to edit) sound arbitrary to me, and if there is a solution along the lines of your question, I don't feel that it's worth following along.

Comment: Deploying the war files as `myip-1.war myip-2.war` should do if I correctly understand the question.

Comment: @OlafKock Thank you for the comment, I agree it's arbitrary, but I was given an assignment that allowed me to only hand in source code. From the looks of things, I will be editing files outside of the source code file and handing those in as well.